# How to narrow down types of a const

Tags: typescript

In the example below, I would like to mandate that all functions should return in a specific format `[string, number]`, but input arguments for those functions can vary.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwFcBOA7AYgeyQWwIbCgF4oBtAZ2CQEsUBzAGihQWwCMIkBdAWAChRIUNCiJQAFADopuJLTIAuKLhQgSnAJREAfLHjJ0WPMD58AxhhQUoAQSiLhosZsI6SAcgsQ3jAIw9e5pYEAEL2IsRiNGAIwIrMbBzOrm7AAO4Y3lBRMf58AtAAwqL5GABmNnng0AAixVVlUMFAA)

```
type ReturnFormat = [string, number]
type Fn = (...args: any[]) => ReturnFormat

const A: Fn = () => ['one', 1]
const B: Fn = (input: number) => ['two', input]

type C = Parameters<typeof A>
type D = Parameters<typeof B>
```

However, when I try to read back the parameters of the function, both `C` and `D` are `any[]`, and not `null` and `input: number`. What should I do to make that happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that you are declaring the variables `A` and `B` with the type `Fn`. The type `Fn` only knows that the arguments should be of type `...any[]`. So when you use this type to declare variables, any specific information about the actual functions you used for the assignment is lost.

You should instead use a generic function to initialise the functions.

```
function createFunction<T extends Fn>(fn: T) { return fn }
```

We can constrain the passed function `T` to be of type `Fn`, but we still return a function of the original type `T`.

When we use this function to create the two variables, you will see that the type information is preserved.

```
const a = createFunction(() => ['one', 1])
// const a: () => [string, number]

const b = createFunction((input: number) => ['two', input])
// const b: (input: number) => [string, number]

const c = createFunction((input: number) => ['two']) // Error: We broke the constaint!
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShwFcBOA7AYgeyQWwIbCgF4oBtAZ2CQEsUBzAGihQWwCMIkBdAWAChRIUNCiJQAFADopuJLTIAuKLhQgSnAJREAfLHjJ0WPMD4nefAMYYUFJaPNII+CGgQpzwKlbFjNhHSQByKwgAxgBGDT4AeiioS2sCXEUfbVIKajpGZjYOHjNeeJtWOwcnFzcPLzEaMARgRWz2JF9-AOAAdwxQqBq6yN4YuKsi5N76phYmlrTKGgYJnK5TQoJzEsdgZ1d3TxRvMYbJjmnAjq6NKEGAUSQkLEUAdWhWO4BraGAAC2gV3BpgACEplMADNtpURPYNlsKrsADwAFSgEAAHpsUAATMhCFBaMQglCKBGaADeUAciFQUAJUAAvkA)

---

A second option would be to make `Fn` generic. But we would have to explicitely give the parameter type to `Fn` everytime we use it to declare a function.

```
type Fn<T extends any[] = void[]> = (...args: T) => ReturnFormat

const a: Fn = () => ['one', 1]
const b: Fn<[number]> = (input: number) => ['two', input]
```

Comment: Great answer, thank you! First one makes sense to me as the generic T `extends` Fn by implementing `...any[]` as args, but extends it to `()` or `(input: number)`, then returns that extended type back as the result.